# Storing color in UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, uikit, uipasteboard

I am trying to store a `UIColor` value in `UIPasteboard.general.color` property.  When I try to access that property it always returns nil on the simulator (haven't tried on device).  I am using iOS10.0 and Swifth 3.2.2 and latest XCode 9.0:

```
                    UIPasteboard.general.color = color
                    if let color = UIPasteboard.general.color {
                        print("color=\(color)")
                    }
                    else {
                        print("no color")
                    }
```

I tried using the `colors` property, but the behavior is the same, but strange: `hasColors` returns true, and `colors` is not nil, but the count of elements is `0`:

```
                    UIPasteboard.general.colors = [color]
                    guard
                        UIPasteboard.general.hasColors, // ok
                        let colors = UIPasteboard.general.colors, // ok
                        0 < colors.count // fail
                    else {
                        print("no color")
                        return
                    }
                    print("color=\(colors[0])")
```

I must be doing something wrong here.  I am using the convenience properties `color` and `colors`.  Here are Apple's specs I'm following: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622085-color and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622078-colors

Comment: For me work just fine in my device I will try in sim

Comment: I Had test in sim and works as well, but I am using the `.color` property not `.colors`, can you please add what are you trying?

Comment: I came up with a work-around that works - I convert the color to a string and store that in the string property.  If you can figure out why color or colors doesn't work that would be great - perhaps it's a simulator configuration.